# Apache ant buildfile looping

Tags: xml, ant, while-loop

Lord of all beginners here.

I'm trying to make a target in a build.xml that restarts itself when it meets a certain condition. I've searched high and low and I can't come up with a solution to make the target...well...loop. 
I'm stuck on this and it's driving me crazy, so any help is welcomed.

Edit:
This is the target I want to loop:

```
<target name="prog" description="executes program">
            <parallel>      
                <daemons>       
                 <exec executable="mch" />
                </daemons>
            </parallel> 
    <exec executable="calculator" inputstring="$var">
        <redirector output="log.txt" />
    </exec>
    <delete file="log.txt" />
</target>
```

The executable creates a file when it closes without finishing. So my  loop condition would be if that file exists or not.

Comment: Don't think of ant as a scripting language.  It's not.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: My target executes a certain program. This program has to close from time to time and I'm looking for a method to restart it automatically until it completely finishes what it has to do. So basically, I'm trying to make the target execute the program, check if the condition for restarting is met and if it is, restart itself.

Comment: Rough spot to be in.  Sounds like you'd want to fail the build if the file is present?  What is the frequency of the abnormal exit? Garbage in / Gospel out is a bad game to play.  Is the something in your power to fix?

Comment: Not the entire build, just the target / part of the target which contains the <exec>. Anyway, after searching for hours I found the Repeat task from Antelope. It behaves like a while loop, except it loops only a defined number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by using Repeat, an additional task from Antelope.

http://antelope.tigris.org/nonav/docs/manual/bk03ch24.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you use waitfor task with checkevery

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html

Sounds similar to the example on the task page

```
<waitfor maxwait="3" maxwaitunit="minute" checkevery="500">
        <http url="http://localhost/myapp/index.html"/>
</waitfor>
waits up to 3 minutes (and checks every 500 milliseconds) for a web server on localhost to     serve up the specified URL.
```