# Ant script looping iteration

Tags: ant, atg

I need to iterate two property in build.xml

```
<target name="sample">
<property name="modules" value="" />
<property name="env" value="" />        
</target>
```

Can any one help me to write looping concept I need to iterate two property at same time. for example ( property " modules " having list of values like = " a, b ,c d )( property "  env " having list of values like = x, y ,z . )
I need value to  get =  modules.env .. it will gives  a.x or b.y in iteration loop. So can any one help how to loop at the same time?

Comment: this one could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483253/apache-ant-buildfile-looping

Answer (score 1):

You can always try javascript for non-trivial tasks

```
<project name="proj">
    <property name="modules" value="a,b,c,d" />
    <property name="env" value="x,y,z,w" />

    <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
       var modules = proj.getProperty("modules").split(",");
       var env = proj.getProperty("env").split(",");
       var size =  Math.min(modules.length, env.length);
       for(var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
           proj.setProperty("mp." + i, modules[i] + "." + env[i]);
       }
    ]]></script>

    <echo message="${mp.0}" />
    <echo message="${mp.1}" />
    <echo message="${mp.2}" />
    <echo message="${mp.3}" />
</project>
```

Comment: Hi Oleg ,Thank you very much . i will try these .

Comment: @Pugal Raja You're welcome. You may up-vote and accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: hi oleg . can i know how to try your code without script tag , bec am using this ant code for ATG ecommerce. build.